# MySQL COUNT with GROUP BY and zero entries

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have 2 tables:

**Table 1.** `options_ethnicity` with the following entries:

```
ethnicity_id ethnicity_name  
1 White  
2 Hispanic  
3 African/American
```

**Table 2.** `inquiries` with the following entries:

```
inquiry_id ethnicity_id  
1 1  
2 1  
3 1  
4 2  
5 2
```

I want to generate a table that shows the number of inquires by ethnicity. My query so far looks like this:

```
SELECT options_ethnicity.ethnicity_name, COUNT('inquiries.ethnicity_id') AS count
FROM (inquiries 
    LEFT JOIN options_ethnicity ON
    options_ethnicity.ethnicity_id = inquiries.ethnicity_id)  
GROUP BY options_ethnicity.ethnicity_id
```

The query gives the correct answer but there is no column for African/American which has 0 results.

```
White 3  
Hispanic 2
```

If I replace the LEFT JOIN with a RIGHT JOIN, I get all 3 ethnicity names, but the count for African/American is wrong.

```
White 3  
Hispanic 2  
African/American 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's an update to this post with what seems to be a working query:

```
SELECT 
    options_ethnicity.ethnicity_name, 
    COALESCE(COUNT(inquiries.ethnicity_id), 0) AS count 
FROM options_ethnicity LEFT JOIN inquiries ON inquiries.ethnicity_id = options_ethnicity.ethnicity_id 
GROUP BY options_ethnicity.ethnicity_id 

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    'NULL Placeholder' AS ethnicity_name, 
    COUNT(inquiries.inquiry_id) AS count 
FROM inquiries 
WHERE inquiries.ethnicity_id IS NULL
```

Comment: The working query - change UNION to `UNION ALL` - no duplicates to remove.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've changed UNION to UNION ALL which should be faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're using a LEFT JOIN, references to the table defined in the LEFT JOIN can be null.  Which means you need to convert this NULL value to zero (in this case):

```
   SELECT oe.ethnicity_name, 
          COALESCE(COUNT(i.ethnicity_id), 0) AS count
     FROM OPTIONS_ETHNICITY oe
LEFT JOIN INQUIRIES i ON i.ethnicity_id = oe.ethnicity_id
 GROUP BY oe.ethnicity_id
```

This example uses [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce), an ANSI standard means of handling NULL values.  It will return the first non-null value, but if none can be found it will return null.  [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) is a valid alternative on MySQL, but it is not portable to other databases while COALESCE is.

---

> In the real database table, there are some entries in the inquires table where the ethnicity_id is NULL, i.e. the ethnicity was not recorded. Any idea on how to get these null values to be counted so that they can be shown?

I think I understand the issue you're facing:

```
   SELECT oe.ethnicity_name, 
          COALESCE(COUNT(i.ethnicity_id), 0) AS count
     FROM (SELECT t.ethnicity_name,
                  t.ethnicity_id
             FROM OPTIONS_ETHNICITY t
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 'NULL placeholder' AS ethnicity_name,
                  NULL AS ethnicity_id) oe
LEFT JOIN INQUIRIES i ON i.ethnicity_id = oe.ethnicity_id
 GROUP BY oe.ethnicity_id
```

This will pickup all the NULL ethncity_id instances, but it will attribute the counting to the "NULL placeholder" group.  IE:

```
ethnicity_name   |  COUNT
------------------------
White            |  3  
Hispanic         |  2
NULL placeholder |  ?
```

Comment: Using COALESCE definitely worked. I'm off to study the COALESCE. Thank you so much OMG Ponies.

Comment: In the real database table, there are some entries in the inquires table where the ethnicity_id is NULL, i.e. the ethnicity was not recorded. Any idea on how to get these null values to be counted so that they can be shown?

Comment: @Mitchell: See the update, let me know if that's what you're after.

Comment: The Union query didn't quite work. It did give the extra "NULL Placeholder" field, but the count was 0 and should have been 4 (using the real database). However, your original query and the UNION gave me an idea, and the following query seems to work:
(Ran out of space, so I'll add another comment.)

Comment: Here's the query that seems to work. Any additional thoughts are welcome, and again, your help is much appreciated.

SELECT  
    options_ethnicity.ethnicity_name,  
    COALESCE(COUNT(inquiries.ethnicity_id), 0) AS count  
    FROM options_ethnicity  
    LEFT JOIN inquiries ON inquiries.ethnicity_id = options_ethnicity.ethnicity_id  
    GROUP BY options_ethnicity.ethnicity_id  

    UNION  

   SELECT  
    'NULL Placeholder' AS ethnicity_name,  
    COUNT(inquiries.inquiry_id) AS count  
    FROM inquiries   
    WHERE inquiries.ethnicity_id IS NULL

Comment: Hmm, I can't figure out how to format the comments, so I've posted the above query at the bottom of the original question.

Comment: @Mitchell: Comments support *very* limited formatting - better to update your question if you want formatting.

Answer (score 3):

You counted a string instead of the right column

```
SELECT options_ethnicity.ethnicity_name, COUNT(inquiries.ethnicity_id) AS count
FROM inquiries 
RIGHT JOIN options_ethnicity ON options_ethnicity.ethnicity_id = inquiries.ethnicity_id  
GROUP BY options_ethnicity.ethnicity_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you "reverse" your query?

```
SELECT 
  options_ethnicity.ethnicity_name, 
  COUNT(inquiries.ethnicity_id) AS count
FROM 
  options_ethnicity
  Left Join inquiries On options_ethnicity.ethnicity_id = inquiries.ethnicity_id
GROUP BY 
  options_ethnicity.ethnicity_id
```

You still *might* need a Coalesce call, but to me, this query makes more sense for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Brandon, thanks for the response. I believe that your "reversed" query is functionally the same as my original query but with "LEFT JOIN" replaced by "RIGHT JOIN" and you're correct that is the proper logic. The COALESCE is still required in order to have empty ethnic categories report 0.